# SQL-Statement to use predefined values list as an SQL-table

Tags: sql, oracle, list

I have a list of ids. e.g. (1, 2, 10). Is it possible to use that list as a table in Oracle ?

I mean something like that:

```
select * from (1, 2, 10) as x, some_table
where x not in some_table.value
```

Comment: Do you attempt to find which numbers in the predefined list is not in the some_table.value? What is the purpose of that table-like usage?

Comment: Exactly. I try to find the numbers which are not contained in some_table.value.

Comment: How many ids in the list? If the number is large may be it is worth using global temporary table. How do you want to get result? Should it be an SQL resultset (like a column) or comma-separated list?

Comment: @YaroslavShabalin The ids in the list will be used in insert statement.

Comment: Do you need to insert only not-existent ids? If so then you probably need [`MERGE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606) statement.

Comment: @YaroslavShabalin Thank you for your comment. Based on it and the answers to this question I made another question about `MERGE`. http://stackoverflow.com/q/22354103/2023524

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select to_number(regexp_substr(str, '[^,]+', 1, level)) ids
--put your comma-delimited list in the string below
  from (select '0,12,2,3,4,54,6,7,8,97' as str from dual)
connect by level <= length(regexp_replace(str, '[^,]+')) + 1
minus
--here comes select from some_table
select level from dual connect by level <= 10;
```

Comment: Sorry but  I understand your solution badly :) The first number (0) is also not in an answer

Comment: What do you think about http://stackoverflow.com/a/14756263/2023524 ? I've found this minute ago (

Comment: @Tony Yes, it makes sense. Actually there are many ways to do it. If you add more information to the question with your complete requirements it will be easier to give advice.

Answer (score 3):

You can use *with* construction

```
with x as (
  select 1 as v from dual
  union all
  select 2 from dual
  union all
  select 10 from dual
)

select *
  from x, some_table
 where x.v not in some_table.value -- <- or whatever condition(s) required
```

Comment: Thank you! It's a nice approach. I can simply generate the expression in my JAVA code.

Comment: I'd use `select * from x where x.v not in (select some_table.value from some_table);` though.

Comment: @ypercube: You're quite right, your condition is better; but my goal was (I've just copied the main query from the question) to show how to use "with" construction

Comment: I understand but this way they will get duplicated results.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a subquery:

```
select st.*
from (select 1 as x from dual union all
      select 2 as x from dual union all
      select 10 as x from dual
     ) t left outer join
     some_table st left outer join
     on st.value = t.x
where st.value is null;
```

Comment: Thank you! I need  all values that are in the list and not in the table. Your way I get all values in the table and not in the list.

Comment: @Tony . . . That makes much more sense.  I fixed the answer.