# Add and delete values in MANY-TO-MANY relationship with MERGE SQL-Statement

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have 3 Tables:

```
A:
-------------
PK_A

B:
-------------
PK_B

A_B:
-------------
K_A K_B PK_AB
```

A_B is a table that "Joined" A and B tables. From my application I get 3 lists:

```
A-List: (PK_A1, PK_A2 ....)

Add-List: (PK_B1, PK_B2 ...)

Delete-List: (PK_B11, PK_B12 ...)
```

For every PK_A from A-List a link should be made between every PK_B from Add-List (added to A_B table).

For every PK_A from A-List a link should be deleted between every PK_B from Delete-List (deleted from A_B table).

K_A K_B Pairs must be unique in A_B table. This is my attempt. It's ok for add-list but I don't know how to use delete-list.

```
MERGE INTO A_B sz
 USING (SELECT *
          FROM (SELECT t.COLUMN_VALUE AS pk_a
                  FROM TABLE (sys.ku$_objnumset (358456, 367346, 367348)) t),
               (SELECT t.COLUMN_VALUE AS pk_b
                  FROM TABLE (sys.ku$_objnumset (338, 339)) t)
    ON (sz.K_B = b.K_B AND sz.K_A = b.K_A)                
WHEN NOT MATCHED
THEN
INSERT     (sz.K_A, sz.K_B, sz.PK_AB)
   VALUES (
             b.K_A,
             b.K_B,
             pk_A_B_seq.NEXTVAL)
```

Related questions I asked before:
[SQL-Statement to use predefined values list as an SQL-table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22327992/2023524)

Comment: Why not use simple `DELETE FROM...` ?

Comment: Yes you are right. :) If it is not possible (or too complicated) with `MERGE` I think how I can do it with `DELETE FROM`

Comment: Well, since you need to delete rows for each PK_A in A-List and each PK_B from Delete-List the simple `DELETE FROM A_B WHERE K_A IN (SELECT PK_A FROM A-List) AND K_B IN (SELECT PK_B FROM Delete-List)` should work just fine :)